# How pass extra param from html to controller

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

Spring Boot 2.5, Thymeleaf

I need when click submit to pass object Product and additional extra param (quantity)

html template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title th:text="${appName}">Category template title</title>
    <link th:href="@{/public/style.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h3 th:text="*{title}"/>
    <form method="post" action="#" th:object="${product}" th:action="@{/product}">
        <input type="hidden" id="id" th:field="*{id}"/>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="name" th:field="*{name}" th:disabled="${isView}"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="created" th:field="*{created}"/>
        <textarea placeholder="Description" rows="5" id="description"
                  th:field="*{description}" th:disabled="${isView}"></textarea>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Price" id="price" th:field="*{price}" th:disabled="${isView}"/>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Currency" id="currency" th:field="*{currency}" th:disabled="${isView}"/>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Images URL(separate by comma)" id="images" th:field="*{images}" th:disabled="${isView}"/>
        <input th:type="${isView} ? hidden : submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here my controller:

```
 @RequestMapping("cart/add")
    public String addProduct(Model model) {
        logger.info("addProduct");
        model.addAttribute("isAdd", true);
        model.addAttribute("product", new Product());
        model.addAttribute("title", "Add Product");
        model.addAttribute("viewMode", ViewMode.ADD);
        return "product";
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/product")
    public String submitProduct(Product product, Model model) {
        logger.info("submitProduct = " + product);
        if (product.getId() == 0) { // add category
            product.setCreated(new Date());
        } else { // update category
            product.setUpdated(new Date());
        }
        return "redirect:/cart";
    }
```

So when click button Submit call `submitProduct` with fill object Product. But I need to pass extra param (as second param in method `submitProduct`) - quantity. 
How I can pass this extra int  param from html to controller?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to access the value directly from the request parameters.

Assuming the quantity value is available in the form as an input field, with a name of `quantity` (looks like it is *not* there at the moment), then you can alter your controller to use this:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
```

And then change the relevant method signature to something like this:

```
public String submitProduct(Product product, Model model,
        @RequestParam(name = "quantity") String quantity) {...}
```

(Field validation of some kind would also be needed, I assume.)